# Eclipse Mars 4.5.1 cannot access internet after first update/plugin install

Tags: eclipse, ssh, eclipse-plugin

I recently installed Eclipse Mars 4.5.1 (for Java Developers) using the Oomph installer. It is installed in my User directory in Windows 7. I was able to start it up, create a hello world app, and it all ran fine.

So far so good....

Then, I go to the "install software" feature under Help and download the C/C++ developer plugin. It downloads and installs fine. When I restart, I am able to build and run C++ binaries.

Again, no problem, yet....

Then, I wanted to install another plugin, PHP Developer. However, when I have Eclipse search the available sites for the package, it cannot find any sites. I tried to do a software update, and it claims it cannot find any of the hosts.

When I try to check my network preferences, I get a "null pointer exception" error report when I try to look at the Network preferences. The error report details indicate this has something to do with ".ssh\known_hosts" file not being found. Therefore, I cannot see what proxies it is using, and the list of known hosts is blank.

Bottom line: after updating itself fine for the first plugin, it appears to be unable to get to any repository for further updates. This happens regardless of what I choose as the first plugin to get.

Comment: Look into eclipse Error Log view and report any related exceptions to eclipse bug tracking system here https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/query.cgi. Does creating missing file in your home directory help?

Comment: There was an overload on download.eclipse.org servers, you may have just had bad timing. Can you try again now, and if it fails again, please provide the log as @dgolovin suggests. http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/cross-project-issues-dev/msg12725.html

Comment: @JonahGraham ah...works now! Thanks!